# If $x>\sqrt{xy}>y$, then $x>y>0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

I am trying to prove the following:

> If $x>\sqrt{xy}>y$, then show that $x>y>0$.

My argument is as follows:

We only need to show $y>0$. Suppose $y<0$. Then, for $\sqrt{xy}$ to be defined, we need $x<0$. Thus, $x<\sqrt{xy}$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $y>0$.

Somehow, my proof doesn't sound "rigorous" enough to me. Is there any other method to prove the result?

Comment: I am fine with that

Comment: There's a *very* minor oversight: You should address that $y=0$ is also problematic.

Comment: Your argument is good, but makes unnecessary use of contradiction. You can turn this into a direct approach like this: Square roots are non-negative, so $x>\sqrt{xy} \geq 0$, which implies $x > 0$. For $\sqrt{xy}$ to be defined (and real), $xy\geq 0$. Therefore, $y \geq 0$. Since we cannot have $y=0$ (why?), we have $y>0$. $\square$

Comment: A final tip: To get the square root symbol to extend over an expression, enclose the expression with `{}`. For example, `$\sqrt{xy}$`.

Comment: @Blue : Your argument  "Since we cannot have $y=0$ (why?)" looks to me like a use of contradiction (not that I have any problems about that).

Comment: @JohnBentin: I should've described my argument "more-direct". Of course, there's nothing wrong with proof by contradiction, *per se*, but since (most of) OP's logic can be turned direct, it's generally considered better form to do so.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for the LaTeX suggestion: I was mistakenly trying with round brackets and it wasn't working. Also thanks for the alternate argument: it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is positive since $x>\sqrt {\text{something}}$ which means that $y$ is also positive since $xy$ is positive and $y\ne \sqrt {xy}$. Therefore $$x^2>xy>y^2$$which in two ways  means that $$x>y>0$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's a correct proof by contradiction, as an alternative by a constructive proof we can observe that $xy=0$ is not a solution then we need

$$xy> 0 \implies x>\sqrt{xy}>0 \quad \land \quad y> 0$$

Comment: You are told that $x>y.$ You want to show that $y>0.$

Comment: @WillR Yes I've added some useless step! Thanks I revise that.

Comment: It's still a bit weird. Why do you start squaring things?

Comment: @WillR Yes indeed I was referring to that part! The chain is $$xy>0 \implies x>0 \implies y>0$$

Comment: Yes, that is the chain.

Comment: @WillR Thanks, I don't know why I took that other complicated way. Yor advice has been enlightening! Bye